# Does docker user defined bridge network support multicast?

Tags: docker, multicast

Despite the fact there is extensive documentation on docker container networking on the public internet, it is to me unclear if the user defined docker bridge network supports multicast out of the box. Does it?
And if no, what should be done to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works out of the box. You can test it with the following experiment.

Create a user defined bridge network:

```
docker network create net1
```

Open three terminals, and on each one run a [Debian](https://www.debian.org/) container:

```
docker run --rm --network="net1" -it debian
```

On each container, do the following:

Install [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/):

```
apt update && apt -y install socat
```

Register the network mask in an environment variable:

```
NETMASK=`ip a | grep global | cut -d" " -f8`
```

Run socat to combine a multicast sender and a multicast receiver, thanks to this [article](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-multicast.html):

```
socat STDIO UDP4-DATAGRAM:224.1.0.1:6666,bind=:6666,range=$NETMASK/16,ip-add-membership=224.1.0.1:`hostname -I`
```

On each terminal, you can now send messages that will be multicasted to others.